# In Ubuntu 14.04, how to disable wpa_supplicant looking for peer to peer (p2p) networks?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-14.04, wpa-supplicant

CVE-2015-1863 - people can maybe break into your computer from anywhere in radio range, by sending specially crafted P2P network management packets.

The [disclosure](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/04/22/8) says you can mitigate the vulnerability by disabling P2P networks in the configuration file, but wpa_supplicant.conf doesn't exist on my system.  How can I disable P2P networks on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Check for updates and install the 'wpa' update. You may have to modify your update preferences to allow "Safe updates. Not tested but believed to be safe." This is the case on Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu, anyway.